# Count SPSS make list of numeric variables

Tags: variables, count, numeric, spss

I have a dataset with both numeric and string variables. 
To count the occurance of a certain value in the whole dataset I use:

*COUNT NREAD=first_variable to last_variable(99).*

This does only work for the numeric variables, but between the first and last variable there are both numeric and string variables. Is there a way to count without having to sort my variables on numeric and string?

Answer (score 2):

Use the SPSSINC SELECT VARIABLES extension command (on Utilities) to define a macro that contains all the variables of the appropriate type and use that with COUNT.

For example,

```
SPSSINC SELECT VARIABLES MACRONAME="!string" /PROPERTIES TYPE=STRING.
```

or

```
SPSSINC SELECT VARIABLES MACRONAME="!numeric" /PROPERTIES TYPE=NUMERIC.
```

and then, say,

```
COUNT thecount=!numeric(99).
```